# C - acsii conversion between char and int

Tags: c, ascii

I have this C code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
     for (char c = "A"; c <= "Z"; c = (char)((int) c + 1))
         printf("%c: %d\n", c, (int) c; 
}
```

A very simple program to print out all capital letters and its ascii numbers

but my result is not quite expected

it actually prints out

```
\: 92
]: 93
^: 94
_: 95
`: 96
a: 97
b: 98
c: 99
d: 100
e: 101
f: 102
g: 103
h: 104
i: 105
j: 106
k: 107
l: 108
m: 109
n: 110
o: 111
p: 112
q: 113
r: 114
s: 115
t: 116
u: 117
v: 118
w: 119
x: 120
y: 121
z: 122
{: 123
|: 124
}: 125
~: 126
: 127
```

Can somebody explain this to me please?

I just started learning C and cannot find out why.

Comment: How did this even compile?

Answer (score 3):

Your program causes undefined behavior when you do this:

```
char c = "A"; c <= "Z"
```

Please use single quotes. Corrected program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char c = 'A';
     for (; c <= 'Z'; c = (char)((int) c + 1))
         printf("%c: %d\n", c, (int) c); 
}
```

`"A"` and `"Z"` are string literals. `'A'` and `'Z'` are character literals

Comment: OK thank u I got it working by replacing the double quote with single quote.

Answer (score 1):

You can't assign to a character variable with `" "`.

`""` is used for *assigning more then one characters.*

```
char c[]="hello world";
```

where as `''` is used for *a single character*.

```
char c='A';
```

---

The proper code should be:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
     char c;

     for (c = 'A'; c <= 'Z'; c = (char)((int) c + 1))
         printf("%c: %d\n", c, (int) c); 
}
```

Comment: `is used for String` - There is no string type in C.

Comment: by string I mean assigning more than one characters, like we do while declaring & initializing an array. I will make it clear